# Timeseries analysis with multiple Columns

Tags: r

I have a timeseries dataframe, with over 1000 columns. Multiple Columns can have the same discrete values. What i want to know is, which 5 Columns do have the same values for the longest time (which 5 for the second longest, etc.),

Lets explain this via an use case:
Its a daily timeseries. Each column represents one footballplayer, each cell is a team, the player is playing for at that time.
So the dataframe looks a  little bit like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       TS            |    Player A      |    Player B      |    Player C      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      2010-08-01     |     Real Madrid  |     Chelsea      |       NA         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      2010-08-02     |     Real Madrid  |     Chelsea      |       NA         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      2010-08-03     |     Real Madrid  |     Chelsea      |       NA         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      2010-08-04     |     Chelsea      |     Chelsea      |       NA         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

So Player A changed the Team on 2010-08-04.
Player C started to play professional football some years later.

Now i would like to know, which 5 players played together for the longest time. Including the case, that all 5 Players did change the team at the same time to the same new team.
Id like to have a result like:
Player A, Player B, Player Z, Player Y, Player W: 1024 days
Player C, Player D, Player E, Player F, Player G: 1021 days
Player A, Plyer B, Player Z, Player X, Player C: 512 days

I'm looking foreward for the solution, or at least for some ideas, how to solve this problem.

Markus

Comment: I'd be happy to take on this question, but you really have to provide some beter sample data (using `dput` so we can see what we are working with)... I doubt that anyone likes to create it for him/herself.

Comment: You should present some sort of attempt at this, if you want help. It really isn't appropriate to ask people to write code for you, but if you have a start, you are far more likely to get help from someone.

Comment: Try grouping by all Player columns and the group with the greatest `nrow()` should be your answer. But also what those above said....

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question, bc i had not a single Idea how to solve this,
but after reading your answers i managed to create a solution:

Lets say teams_ts is my dataframe.
I extract each row, and filter out the NAs. I transpose the row into a column vector.
The rownames of this new vector are the names of the players, playing for a team at that day.

```
for (l in 1:nrow(teams_ts)) {
df <- t(teams_ts[l, !is.na(teams_ts[l,])])
```

Then i create a vector with the teams, which are present in the new column vector. I get rid of the first entry, bc it represents the day.

```
df_teams <- names(table(df))[-1]
```

For each team, i look for the players, playing in this team. This is done with rownames of the filtered column vector.

```
for (k in 1:length(df_teams)){
    temp <- rownames(df)[df == df_teams[k]]
```

This creates a character vector which I collapsed into one string. This string, with the day and the Team is stored in the dataframe player combinations.

```
    df_temp <- data.frame(names = paste(temp,  collapse = ", "),
                      day = teams_ts$Date[l],
                      team = df_teams[k])
    player_combinations <- rbind(player_combinations, df_temp)
  }
}
```

Now i can answer my question via the group by with nrows.:

```
final <- player_combinations %>% group_by(names) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())
```

In the end, thank you for your input